# Using stirling's factorial formula

Tags: c++, formula

I'm trying to write a code that calculates the approximate factorial of a number using Stirling's formula.

Here's the line that calculates it:

```
appFact = pow(exp, -num) * pow(num, num) * sqrt(2 * num * PI);
```

The error comes in at pow(exp, -num) with pow underlined in red.

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "pow" matches the argument list 25
```

The variables are declared as:

```
float num, num2, num3, num4, MEAN, stanDev, VARI, appFact, exp; 
readFile >> num >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;  
appFact = pow(exp, -num) * pow(num, num) * sqrt(2 * num * PI);
```

Comment: Please show the declarations of `exp` and `num`. Especially `exp`. Without having checked Stirling's formula, there is also the possibility that you've exchanegd `exp` and `num` in the first call to `pow` --  perhaps you could also provide the formula?

Comment: float num, num2, num3, num4, MEAN, stanDev, VARI, appFact, exp;

readFile >> num >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;

appFact = pow(exp, -num) * pow(num, num) * sqrt(2 * num * PI);

Formula is e^-n*n^n*sqrt(2*pi*n)

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to figure out what the e actually is

Comment: With type `float` for both args, like `pow( 1.0f, 1.0f )`, it should compile nicely, doesn't it? Perhaps Intellisense gets confused. And if this is your actual code then there should perhaps first be an assignment to `exp`, like `exp = 2.718281828;`. By the way, the 'e' in that formula is, as I recall, short for "Euler's number", not for "exponent". Cheers, & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

Try including the appropriate header file:

```
#include <cmath>
```

If that doesn't help, note that the implementation of `pow()` is in the `std` namespace. So:

```
appFact = std::pow(exp, -num) * std::pow(num, num) * std::sqrt(2 * num * PI);
```

Comment: Same problem;  IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::pow" matches the argument list  26

Comment: So, what types are `exp` and `num`? That's the "argument list" the message is referring to.

Comment: If you hadn't declared `exp` at all, you would have got a compiler error when you tried to compile your code. I wouldn't rely on IntelliSense to tell you about compiler errors; generally it works best when your code *already* compiles (mostly) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Stirling's formula! The denominator in the fraction (n/e) of course is Euler's e, e = 2.71828 (5 digits). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant).